# How do I implement secure OAuth2 consumption in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, salesforce, firebase, firebase-security, angularfire

I'm setting up oauth2 with Salesforce connect using AngularJS. When I attempt the initial GET using $http I get CORS errors - Access-Control-Allow-Origin not allowed for my client. However, using the hack below in my controller function works.

Is there a better way to do this in AngularJs given that I don't have control over the server? My backend is Firebase so it would be great if I could do this through FIrebase like I can for Facebook :

```
$scope.auth = function () {

    var authUrl = $scope.AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT + 
            "?response_type=token" +
            "&client_id="    + $scope.CLIENT_ID +
            "&redirect_uri=" + "https://www.xyz/";

    window.location = authUrl ;
```

Comment: You can consider using the `$location` service to do the redirect for you: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location, but otherwise this appraoch seems fine.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. perhaps you can point me in the right general direction on a related qs? I'm in a world of pain with same origin - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541976/what-is-the-correct-architectural-pattern-for-cross-domain-rest-call-in-angularj

Answer (score 0):

The cors issue happens when make asynchronous call to different server via browser.

So it doesn't appear if the call is made from another server. so you have to use a proxy server which in turn makes a call to your actual server.

You can try the below proxy server which is straightforward.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors-anywhere

or you can write your own proxy server which runs on the same domain as your client app and proxies your request to the secured server.