# What is the correct architectural pattern for cross domain REST call in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, salesforce, angularfire

I've created an AngularJS service that is hitting the Salesforce REST API directly from the client. However, I haven't been able to get it working due to same origin restrictions. Even when accessing non authenticated REST services and trying both $http, $http.json and Ajax. I've also tried lots of combinations of Json, Jsonp etc.

Given that I've had so many issues I'm thinking that my general approach is incorrect. Perhaps I need to setup a proxy server for this? My backend is Firebase so I don't currently have my own server.

I don't believe that the Salesforce API supports CORs and I cannot change that.

Here is an example of what I tried using $http and Ajax.

```
return $http.jsonp('https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/',{
headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'
}}). 
                success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

                    callback(data);
                    console.debug(data.json);
                }).
                error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.debug("getVersions: failed to retrieve data: "+eval(data));
                });


$.ajax({
              url: 'https://na15.salesforce.com/services/data',
          type: "GET",
              dataType: "jsonp",
              beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
                                  xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
                                  xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
                                  xhrObj.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
                              },
              success: function (data) {
                  console.debug(data);
                  callback(data);
              },
              error: function(data) {

              }
          });
```

Comment: Yes, if the Salesforce endpoints don't support CORS then you cannot access their services from the client only. You'll need run a simple proxy server on the same domain that your web app is server, which forwards requests to the SalesForce API endpoints and sends your their results.

Comment: I setup a simple Ruby Sinatra proxy and it works perfectly. My app is HTTPS running on multiple subdomains so I still set the access control response header in the RUby code - response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'

Comment: Awesome! Feel free to email support@firebase.com or post another question on StackOverflow if you have any other questions.

Comment: @Anant is totally correct. there is no client-side solution to this other than a proxy on the **same** domain

Answer (score 0):

You need to go into Remote Settings within SalesForce then CORS and whitelist the domain name...

I had the same issue and it seemed to have resolved the issue.

See if this helps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33663234/angularjs-saleforce-attachment-with-http-request-troubleshooting-help-needed)